# Sklearn - GridSearchCV with v_measure_score is NOT the same

Tags: scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to use **GridSearchCV** with **v_measure_score**
and compare the result
with another method **WITHOUT GridSearchCV**.

The best score of **v_measure_score by for-loop** is **0.69816019299** with **percentile 27**;
the best score of **GridSearchCV** is **0.565562627046** with percentile **12**.

In my opinion, the results should be the same.
I've checked my code several times but still cannot figure out the reason.
The following is my code:

**GridSearchCV**

```
estimators = [('tfIdf', TfidfTransformer()), ('sPT', SelectPercentile()), ('kmeans', cluster.KMeans())]
pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
params = dict(tfIdf__smooth_idf=[True],
              sPT__score_func= [f_classif], sPT__percentile=range(100, 0, -1),
              kmeans__n_clusters=[clusterNum], kmeans__random_state=[0], kmeans__precompute_distances=[True])
v_measure_scorer = make_scorer(v_measure_score)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params, scoring=v_measure_scorer)
grid_search_fit = grid_search.fit(apiVectorArray, yTarget)
```

**v_measure_score by for-loop**

```
bestPercent = [-1, -1]
for percent in xrange(100, 0, -1):
    transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True)
    apiVectorArrayTFIDF = transformer.fit_transform(apiVectorArray)
    apiVectorFit = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=percent).fit(apiVectorArrayTFIDF, yTarget)
    k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=clusterNum, random_state=0, precompute_distances=True).fit(apiVectorFit.transform(apiVectorArrayTFIDF))

    if v_measure_score(yTarget, k_means.labels_) > bestPercent[1]:
        bestPercent[0] = percent
        bestPercent[1] = v_measure_score(yTarget, k_means.labels_)
```

I tried to add color on my code but failed.
Sorry for your eyes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because **GridSearchCV** uses Cross-Validation to fit the data, the score is different from for-loop.